# Facebook notification exploit?

Tags: facebook, security, blogger

I recently got a notification for being tagged in a comment on facebook by a friend (on the actual facebook UI - I have not seen any emails pertaining to this). The notification seemed, and probably is legitimate. However, upon clicking it, I got redirected without warning to some kind of burner blogspot domain - <40-character string>.blogspot.de, and through there, immediately got redirected to another obviously illegitimate phishing site.

My question is - is this a known exploit? I.e. hijacking an account, which then tags people on a blogspot post, leading to legitimate notifications which when clicked redirect you to the blogspot page?

UPDATE: A scan with Windows Defender revealed an infection with TrojanDownloader:Win32/Upatre

Comment: Do you think you had the "Urate" infection _before_ clicking the link in the email? What is this "Urate"? (A quick Google didn't seem to return anything meaningful?)

Comment: Apologies for typo. I have daily scans and this is what picked it up for the first time, so I'm inclined to believe the two are connected.

Comment: Just to clarify, is the link in the notification email a legitimate Facebook URL?

Comment: I haven't actually received a notification email - it is just an actual notification on the facebook UI.